# Netbeans trys to connect to deleted jdbc

Tags: oracle, netbeans, eclipselink

Here is how setup looks like:

- ApplicationServer - GlassFish
- Database Server - Oracle 10g2
- Persistance Library - EclipseLink
- Faces Framework - IceFaces

My Problem is that everytime I change the database connection the application/eclipselink stops working, failing to find the Persistance Unit.

After loosing a whole day trying to figure it out. I decided to delete all the information about connections and persistance units and use only one new created.

Building the project was not a problem, but running it I get an error, pointing that the there is a validationexception and a persistance unit with a given name was not found. That name is deleted and is't descriped in the persistance.xml nor in the sun-resources.xml. There is no such entry in the Services in Netbeans.

Have you seen such an error, and how can I make sure, that netbeans doesn't store information on places I can't reach from the IDE? How is it so that my application is looking for something that isn't listed anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay next time I have to think more, instead of asking the question here. So my problem was the cache directory of Netbeans 6.9.1.

Deleted the cache directory and everything started working again.

I hope that this problem is fixed in the next releases. it can be real pain in ... :)